# A.J. Galitzer's Ph.D. thesis: On the moduli space of closed polygonal linkages on the 2-sphere

Tags: reference-request, linkage

Recently I became curious about moduli spaces of linkages and so I found and began reading some papers of Kapovich and Millson.  In the paper [Hodge theory and the art of paper folding](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ekapovich/EPR/art.pdf), the Ph.D. thesis of A. Galitzer is cited. I found other citations to it in the literature, but I could not find an electronic copy.

Does anyone have a copy on hand, or are the results published elsewhere?  The main result seems to be a characterization of the possible side lengths of closed polygons on the unit sphere.

If I were still in living in the states, I would make a visit to U. of M.'s library to check it out, since I have friends in the area. Alas, I am overseas.

Comment: Perhaps contact Louis Theran, who replied knowledgeably to the question, [Is a rhombus rigid on a sphere or torus? And generalizations](http://mathoverflow.net/q/40463/6094).

Comment: Also, do you know that K.&M. wrote a paper entitled, "On the Moduli Space of a Spherical Polygonal Linkage"? [Citeseer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.38.3992).

Comment: If someone is at an US based institution, it appears to be cataloged in ProQuest (but being overseas I cannot get the full text).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I am aware of that paper, indeed, they also cite her thesis for the aforementioned results. Thanks for the pointer to Louis Theran as well.

Comment: You probably already know that Amy Galitzer's Ph.D. adviser was John Millson. You could write to him [@Univ Maryland](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~millson/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a copy [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1acr8l38pwx5w8v/AJ-Galitzer-PhD.pdf).

(A [note](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/91/262) on linking to academic papers.)

Comment: Many thanks! And that is indeed an important discussion in the meta.matheducators page.